# Laravel get users that are not in a team

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a users table and a salesTeams table.

a user can be a leader to only one salesteam. a salesteam can only have one leader.

on the salesTeams i have a leader_id (users.id).
on the users table i also have a role_id column (role id 3 is for the leader)
On the users model I have the function

```
public function salesTeam(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\SalesTeam', 'leader_id');
}
```

to retrieve a users team, if any.

On the UserRoles model i have the function

```
public function scopeOnlyLeaders($query) {

        $query->where('id', 3)->with('users');

        return $query;
    }
```

to get all users that have the role id coresponding to leaders

I need a function that retrieves all the leaders that are not currently assigned to a team.
Right now my only solution is raw sql but I'm sure i've overlooked something in the documentation of eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public function scopeOnlyLeaders($query) {

    $query->with(['users' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('users.*')
        $query->leftJoin('salesteam', 'salesteam.id', '=', 'users.leader_id')
            ->whereNull('leader_id');
    }]);

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: this does the exact same thing. I want users that currently are not assigned to any team. So the ones whose id is not present in the leader_id column in salesteams table